# MySQL is not running in xampp server. I tired to change the port number but it shows that access is denied

Tags: mysql, server, xampp

I used to work on xampp and stop MySQL from the services and start it in xampp everything was fine. Later I got an error that said the port 3306 can't be used. So I tried to change it to port number 3307. I could change it in other places but when it comes to changing it in xampp --> config--> service and port setting --> mysql and change the main port to 3307 and coming to save it, it shows an error that is access is denied. How I can fix this? thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64yIH.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must start XAMPP with administrator privileges